# Есть ли аналог INSERT - on conflict для команды UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
        id SERIAL UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        username TEXT NOT NULL,
        login TEXT NOT NULL,
        password TEXT NOT NULL,
        email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        create_date Timestamp,
        access CHARACTER(10) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT user_unique UNIQUE (login, password)
);
```

И есть запрос:

```
with ins as (
  INSERT INTO test (id, username, login, password, email, create_date, access)
  VALUES (DEFAULT, 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', now()::timestamp, 'asd')
  on conflict on constraint user_unique do nothing
  returning id
)
```

Нужен такой же запрос который вернет `true` или `false` только о результате обновления `UPDATE` но для него нет `on conflict`:

```
UPDATE users
SET  username = (?), login = (?), password = (?), email = (?), access = (?)
WHERE id = (?);
```

Как это можно еще решить? Чтобы все-таки получить `true/false` как результат столкнулся ли запрос с `CONSTRAINT user_unique UNIQUE (login, password)` или успешно обновил данные?

Comment: А зачем именно true/false. можно анализировать код ошибки после выполнения запроса. Или в условие добавить not exists что бы update ничего не обновил в случае нарушения ключа и анализировать количество обработанных записей

Comment: @Mike я просто из метода который добавляет пользователей хочу вернуть получилось или нет, мне любой  критерий по которому я смогу этот флаг сформировать подойдет.

Comment: Метод же может проверить наличие и номер ошибки при выполнении запроса ?

Comment: *мне любой критерий по которому я смогу этот флаг сформировать подойдет* Количество изменённых записей - именно его должен по идее возвращать UPDATE. *столкнулся ли запрос с CONSTRAINT user_unique UNIQUE (login, password)* Странный констрейнт. Вряд ли у Вас могут быть два одинаковых логина... а если могут - то надо что-то менять...

Comment: @Akina да могут, надо менять вы правы. Но все равно даже если и не могли был-бы другой CONSTRAINT и надо было бы с ним делать то-же самое... предположим пользователь хочет сменить имя пользователя на какое-то уже существующее в базе, а двумя запросами делать это не хочется... явно что как-то можно одним

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать следующим образом:

```
WITH updated AS (
    UPDATE users
    SET username = (?), login = (?), password = (?), email = (?), access = (?)
    WHERE id = (?) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (?) AND login = (?))
    RETURNING id)
SELECT CAST (CASE
                WHEN u.id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
             END AS BOOLEAN
            ) AS result        
FROM (VALUES (0)) AS t(f)
LEFT JOIN updated u ON (1=1);
```

Comment: Как ни крути всё равно сохраняется вероятность исключения. Всё это мартышкин труд. В лучшем случае надо делать через хранимую процедуру, если она может отлавливать и гасить исключения.